# CSS - Materializecss - Modal top property overridden automatically

Tags: css, modal-dialog

I'm trying to place some tuto modals on my website, so I place them in `position:fixed` and want them to be at the top and left property I give ..

It seems that top property is automaticalluy changed to `top:10%` in my inspector ... Why ? :/

The [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amm85rrs/13/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `top: 10%;` is *injected* as inline style to the `#test` element, and by that has a "higher rank" since it is the last style definition in the chain :

ghpages-materialize.css **→** internal `<style>` **→** inline `style=".."`

However, you can use `!important` to overrule the inline style :

```css
#test {
  position:fixed;
  margin:0px;
  top:400px !important;
  left:0px;
  width:400px;
  height:160px;
  border-radius:40px;
}
```

updated fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/amm85rrs/14/**